# How to delete users from account-ui meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm making a meteor app and using accounts ui and bootstrap and all that stuff but I'm wondering if there is a way I can be like an admin and delete users because recently people have been making inappropriate usernames and such..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can delete users pretty easy like. having a template protected just to `admin accounts` and on that template have a list with the users, based on that create an event like this.

```
Template.example.events({
 'click #deleteAccount':function(){
    meteor.users.remove({_id:this._id}) 
  }
})
```

and use an allow method like this.

```
Meteor.allow({
 remove:function(){
   //if is admin return true;
  }
})
```

But thats not a good practice, why? check this [David Weldon -common-mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes)

> if there is a way I can be like an admin?

For accomplish this on a better way use the [meteor-roles package](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles),

With this you can can protect templates with

```
{{if isInRole 'Admin'}}
 <!--show admin stuff-->
   {{else}}
 <!--sorry just admin stuff here -->
{{/else}}
```

and create basic admin accounts.

```
if(Meteor.users.find().count() === 0){
  var users = [
      {name:"Admin Example",email:"supersecretaccount@gmail.com",roles:['Admin']}
    ];

  _.each(users, function (user) {
    var id;

    id = Accounts.createUser({
      email: user.email,
      password: "amore251327",
      profile: { name: user.name }
    });

    if (user.roles.length > 0) {
      Roles.addUsersToRoles(id, user.roles);
    }

  });  
}
```

Try it